# Which algorithm is used for the functions date_sunrise, date_sunset and date_sun_info?

Tags: php

There are different algorithms available to compute the position of the sun from which sunrise and sunset can be derived. They have different accuracy. Does anyone know which is used for the PHP functions `date_sunrise`, `date_sunset` and `date_sun_info`?

Comment: PHP is open source: http://php.net/downloads.php   grab it and examine the code for those functions.

Comment: or look at the source at [github.com/php](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/date/php_date.c) line 4602

Answer (score 9):

*Please note this answer was given for PHP 5.5, but is still accurate as of PHP 8.3.*

The `date_sunrise` and `date_sunset` functions call the C function `php_do_date_sunrise_sunset` in [date.c](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/php-5.5.5/ext/date/php_date.c#L4601), which uses the `timelib` library.

The `timelib` function `timelib_astro_rise_set_altitude` is well commented ([see source](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/php-5.5.5/ext/date/lib/astro.c#L207)), and uses the [generalised sunrise equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sunrise_equation#Generalized_equation) to calculate the diurnal arc.

The `date_sun_info` function also calls the same `timelib` function.

Comment: I notice you've not accepted any answers to your questions — have you seen [How does accepting an answer work](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)?

Answer (score 2):

PHP uses **public domain algorithms by Paul Schlyter**, some more info on his website: http://www.stjarnhimlen.se/comp/riset.html

Other, more accurate, algorithms for sunrise and sunset time calculations are the ones described in **Astronomical Algorithms by Jean Meeus**. The [NOAA Sun calculator](https://www.esrl.noaa.gov/gmd/grad/solcalc/) as well as [Sunrise-sunset site](http://sunrise-sunset.org) are using those improved calculations.

You can find a PHP implementation of such algorithms at this [github project](https://github.com/mcorne/astronomical-algorithms)